# What does it mean to be invited to work for three days after an interview?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, new-job, germany

I interviewed today with a medium-size (around 100 employees) German software company. I solved all the technical questions quite well and I think I did pretty well also with HR questions. My interviewers were nice and friendly and I believe they like me and I do like them so far. One of the interviewers was the technology manager and the other was the HR manager.

After I finished the interview they showed me around the offices and then at the end they said that they usually invite candidates for 3 days to work full-time at the company. They said they do that so that they get to know me better and see me coding more than what I coded during the interview, and also said that it's a good opportunity for the candidate to see if he likes the company/atmosphere or not.

I live in the middle of Germany and I had to travel for 4 hours for the interview. They said they will invite me to stay in a hotel during the three days.

My questions:

1. Is it common for companies to invite candidates for couple of days like that?
2. Would a company invite multiple candidates for something like that or would they normally only invite the candidate that they are mostly interested in? Since they will be responsible for the costs of staying and so on.
3. Should I expect to be paid for the three working days?

I don't have any experience in the industry hiring processes much so that's why I'm asking!

Edit:

they also asked about my expected salary and I replied.

Comment: Soooo... if you're currently employed, they expect you to use 3 of your vacation days for this somewhat-excessively-long interview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it common for companies to invite candidates for couple of days like that?

It's getting more common to invite someone for *one* day, I had not heard of three yet.

> Would a company invite multiple candidates [...] ?

Probably not. Hosting a candidate comes at a cost to the company, too. Expenses are probably peanuts, but to actually make a decision for or against hiring you, someone has to work with you and/or supervise you. They'd not want to do this with more than one candidate per job opening.

> Should I expect to be paid for the three working days?

Probably not. Most companies I heard of consider it a fair deal: they pay for all expenses and the people that work with you/supervise you, you spent your time. Both parties pay part of the whole a cost. As you probably won't be working on production code or at least not on code they will actually release, you aren't actually *working* for them. They don't gain anything from your three days except a better insight in your work. Most likely you will work on a problem they already solved. They might not tell you to not demotivate you. But only if they already implemented it themselves, they will be able to judge your skill and compare it to their other developers.

> What does it mean to be invited to work for three days after an interview?

It's a good thing. Your interviewers think you might be a good fit. They would not expend time and/or money if they had serious doubts.

Comment: Since I'm just a recent graduate, can you give me hints what should I prepare? I'm weak in using git, so I will be doing git tutorials. I also never used junit for testing in Java so I will also try to learn how to use it for testing. Actually I never done proper testing before, so I will try to learn how this is done (I used to create a main method to test my code). Other than that, what do you recommend I should prepare to show that I'm a good developer who can write high quality commercial code?

Comment: Any advise will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you are pretty well prepared. Do a few coding excercises and you are good to go.

Comment: you are awesome!

Comment: Once again: Not getting paid for working three days (and it doesn't matter if the work actually helps the company or not) would be illegal in Germany. If they want to do this, this would be a big red flag for me - Who knows which laws the don't care about apart from this one?

Comment: @dirkk Exactly I would pass on the company or if you really really need the money only work their for a year and start looking for a better employer as soon as you start.

Comment: @dirkk You are *not* working, so it's *not* illegal. Nothing you produce will be used for anything but judging your abilities. You do not have an *Arbeitsvertrag*. Tell me which law says you need to pay someone for coming and doing stuff? Did you get paid for any interviews yet? Probably not. This is nothing but a three-day-interview. Call it a single-person-assessment-center. I'm not sure if I would like it, but it's not illegal.

Comment: @nvoigt "coming and doing stuff" is usually what I would call _working_. By your logic my employer could also decide to not pay me if the (I am in IT) software product I develop is never released. I think the whole argument whether it has to be paid is quite a lengthy argument (and I am not a lawyer) and too long for this comment thread. Just one example in favor of my argument: http://www.jenapolis.de/2014/03/05/probearbeit-muss-bezahlt-werden-fau-erfurtjena-treibt-lohn-im-immergruen-jena-ein/

Comment: @dirkk Where do you draw the line between an interview and work? *When* is it work in your opinion? The link only says someone paid. No judge decided if he *had* to pay. The company did not want to go to court over petty change. Like any bigger company. That's not a good case for legality of something. And what would you pay someone? Minimum wage? If you pay me minimum wage, I'd be insulted. I'm happy to show my skills for free if I want to get hired. If I'd charge fairly, an 8-hour day minimum wage would be enough to keep me around from 08:00 till 08:30.

Comment: @nvoigt All your points are true and I am sure lawyers and courts would have also different opinions on the matter. Based on my understanding of the law and the §612 BGB I would assume 3 days work of coding is _work_, as I would normally would just do it if I get paid. Also, I certainly agree with you that I would expect to get paid more than minimum wage, but this is just the lower threshold the law requires an employer to pay. But I don't really get why you would be insulted by minimum wage, but you would be fine with not getting paid at all?

Comment: @dirkk That's easy, we do it all the time: I do flip burgers for free at a friends BBQ. Offer me minimum wage as compensation and I'd decline. If you are looking for a burger flipper, hire one. But not me. I got a job, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak for Germany (so feel free to stop reading if you like), but my general observations:

1. Is it common? - I've seen it in the UK a few times, and it is becoming more common.  As people like Google have found, interviews are only of so much value (and especially the mind bender questions).  A scenario like this is a much better way of seeing, both the way you work, and the way you may fit into the team, and show they are serious about team fit over how well you can present yourself in interview.  So it's not common, but not something to be concerned about.
2. You need to ask them - They may have budget to bring in multiple people, but the main thing is they are serious enough about you to take this step, so concentrate on that.
3. Payment - Again you need to ask, I've seen companies who do this who expect you to donate your time.  I think the fact they are paying for accommodation (and travel?) will be a sign they will pay, but clarify first.  It's a fair question to ask, so don't be embarrassed.

My gut feel on this is that it depends on the work they expect you to do whilst there.  If it's still interview like (or straight forward project work, with good reviews of code/documentation etc), then use the opportunity to get the job.  If they throw you into something mission critical or causing them real issues, I'd watch they aren't just trying to get contractor help for free/cheap.  I'd expect them to spend time with you, show you how they work, and see how you fit, not for you to solve their biggest headache, that'd be a red flag to me.

Comment: I will expand on a few things from a German perspective. It is definitely not common at all here, I guess it is much less common than in the US/UK. In general, German industry is quite slow in picking up the new hiring trends from the US. Also, regarding payment they absolutely have to pay you here, considering the new Mindestlohngesetz (minimum wages) - Also, if they would not pay you it would be a big red flag for me.

Comment: @dirkk so yo mean that it's not common to do that here. So what does it tell then?

Comment: @dirkk and how much do you think I will be payed per day?!

Comment: It can mean many things. Could be they are just super-hip and follow every new trend anyone is telling them or they could be doing serious HR research and have found that this is the best approach for hiring staff. Or it could be that they try to rip you off and get people to work for free for them. How much they pay I have no idea, as I have never heard of such a thing in Germany, and it just depends on the company. You will (and absolutely should!) have to ask.

Comment: From the US (where I personally have never seen this): what happens if the applicant already has a current job? Is he/she expected to use 3 vacation days for the work experience? That's a lot to ask for, in my opinion.

Comment: Yepp, you need to take leave or be "sick"

Comment: In the US and I just landed a new job.  More than one company I talked with had coming in for a full day of work as part of the process. The one I took kept it to a few hours in a contrived situation.  This is probably more common in companies using the Extreme programming practice of "pairing" where you work side by side with another programmer on the same computer, usually with two keyboards and mice to solve a problem.  It's very popular and there are many pros, however, if you don't mesh with the team it won't work.

Comment: I haven't heard of this in the UK and I am a TU activist so would have heard of any new sketchy employment practices

Comment: Well I have to say in my experience just about all IT places are non-union shops so not too surprising.   I've had 2 bites of this,band actually having tried it, I ruled both employers out based on what I saw.  So not really a sketchy thing, actually useful from the eemployee side.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager how is this useful from the employee side? I can only see it useful from the side that I will get the chance to know the company better and their teams.

Comment: Exactly, remember an interview is a 2 way thing, same for this. You are as much seeing if this is where you want to work, how you may gel with co-workers, what the commute is like, what lunchtime is like, what is day to day life like? In my case I saw it and said the place wasn't for me, instead of starting a job and thinking "what have I done?"